# How to increase UIView height which contains UIStackView

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have a custom view which contains a label, label can have multiple line text. So i have added that label inside a UIStackView, now my StackView height is increasing but the custom view height doesn't increases. I haven't added bottom constraint on my StackView. What should I do so that my CustomView height also increases with the StackView.

```
 let myView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TestView", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! TestView
    myView.lbl.text = "sdvhjvhsdjkvhsjkdvhsjdvhsdjkvhsdjkvhsdjkvhsjdvhsjdvhsjdvhsjdvhsjdvhsjdvhsjdvhsdjvhsdjvhsdjvhsdjvhsdjvhsjdvhsdjvhsdjvhsjdvhsdjvhsjdvhsdjvhsdjvhsdjvhsjdv"
    myView.lbl.sizeToFit()
    myView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: myView.frame.size.height)
    myView.setNeedsLayout()
    myView.layoutIfNeeded()

    self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

I want to increase my custom view height as per my stackview height.
Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Example of stackView constraints with its superview.
Also superview should not have constraints for its height.

[image]

Comment: Making the contraints `>=` did the job for me. Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the top and bottom anchors of your custom view to be constrained to the top and bottom anchors of your stackview.  As your stackView grows, it will push that bottom margin along.  Here's a programmatic example:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    private lazy var stackView = UIStackView()
    private lazy var addLabelButton = UIButton(type: .system)

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let stackViewContainer = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
       stackViewContainer.backgroundColor = .yellow
        stackViewContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackViewContainer)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical

        addLabelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(addLabelButton)
        stackViewContainer.addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // Container constrained to three edges of its superview (fourth edge will grow as the stackview grows
            stackViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            stackViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            stackViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),

            // stackView constraints - stackView is constrained to the
            // for corners of its contaier, with margins
            {
                // Stackview has a height of 0 when no arranged subviews have been added.
                let heightConstraint = stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
                heightConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
                return heightConstraint
            }(),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewContainer.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),

            // button constraints
            addLabelButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            addLabelButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewContainer.centerXAnchor)
            ])

        addLabelButton.setTitle("New Label", for: .normal)
        addLabelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addLabel(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view = view
    }

    private(set) var labelCount = 0

    @objc func addLabel(sender: AnyObject?) {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Label #\(labelCount)"
        labelCount += 1
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Note that when the UIStackView is empty, its height is not well defined.  That is why I set its heightAnchor constraint to 0 with a low priority.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add bottom constraint on your UIStackView. This will help auto layout in determining the run time size of UIStackView.

Now create instance of your custom UIView but do not set it's frame and add it to UIStackView. Make sure you Custom UiView has all the constraints set for auto layout to determine it's run time frame.
This will increase height of both UIView and UIStackView based on content of UIView elements.

For more details you can follow my detailed answer on this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57954517/3339966