# How to change an UIView size according to its content?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

So I have a checkbox and a label, I put them together within a UIView so I can use the checkbox and label as one component later on and for other projects, the thing is  I want the view to change size (specifically width) according to the label text length. So far I can only seem to get this. The red part is a UIStackView containing the Checkbox and the label, the blue part is the UIView Class containing the stackView. What can I do to modify the Views size to match the Stackviews size, so if the label gets shorter so will the View. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to size a UIStackView depending on its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591260/how-to-size-a-uistackview-depending-on-its-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use constraints. In this instance, you want the UIStackView to have constraint anchors each with a set value of zero for each side of the blue UIView - this will fill the blue UIView with the UIStackView.

Assuming that you will want the checkbox to remain the same size, you can set a width and height constraint, with a leading constraint of 0 to the left edge of the UIStackView.

Lastly, give the label constraints of 0 for the top and bottom edges of the UIStackView, and some number value for the leading and trailing constraints so that is has a bit of padding on either side of it (away from checkbox and right edge).

**UIStackView Constraints**

```
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

**CheckBox Constraints**

```
checkBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
checkBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
checkBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
checkBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: given_height).isActive = true
checkBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: given_width).isActive = true
```

**Label Constraints**

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkBox.trailingAnchor, constant: given_space).isActive = true
label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

> In order for the view's height to adjust to the label (if its associated text is longer than one line), then add the following line of code: `label.numberOfLines = 0`

*Please note that your blueView will also need constraints.*

You can find out more about constraints [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuCx6dGaY1g).

Or if you prefer to use storyboards, you don't have to programatically add the constraints - see this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/811496-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-getting-started).

Comment: Oh great! Thanks for the response, mate! The thing is I need the blueView to change size and "shrink down" to match the redView (stackView) not the stackView to match the blueview ):

Comment: Ah nevermind I just did what you told me and changed the hugging priority for the elements within the view!  Thanks a lot for your help, mate!